# Form with checkboxes and hidden values on reload page

Tags: checkbox, onload

I don't know if this makes any sense but I have a form with checkboxes and once the user clicks on the box it will show a hidden message. But once I reload the browser, the checkbox is still checked off but the hidden message is no longer there.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="CB6" name="" value=""> 

<table name="hidden" id="hidden" style="display:none;">
<tr>
<td>It works</td>
</tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#CB4').click(function() {
if($(this).is(':checked')) {
$('#hiddenRAcost').show();
} else {
$('#hiddenRAcost').hide();
}
});
});
</script>
```

Is there like an onload function or something when a user reloads the page, it can run that script?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<body onload="myFunc()">
...
</body>
```

Whenever the body loads (or page), `myFunc()` will run, so you can use this to check.

Answer (score 0):

Just have it look for the checkbox state when the page loads as well as when it is clicked.

Take this code: 
`if($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('#hiddenRAcost').show();
    } else {
    $('#hiddenRAcost').hide();
    }`

And place it directly in your $(document).ready() handler. If you want, you could make it a function and then use that in both the click event handler and the onload.